# Kendo Drop DownList does not show first item after load

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

My kendo Drop down list does not show the first item when its loaded,
as of the following:

dataSource: mydata,

valuePrimitive: true,

autoBind: false,

dataTextField: "Text",

Comment: you mean that first item is not selected by default ?

Comment: I was wrong a little, you should set autoBind property to true, or just remove it, as in this [dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/ehiBE/2)

Comment: can you reproduce your issue in dojo ?

Comment: Try to set autoBind to true

Comment: repurposing old questions is not acceptable here.

Comment: Show your code.